# Gedmo Doctrine mapping restricted to strings - integer not available?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I get the following error when running `doctrine:migrations:diff` after building a Doctrine mapping file with type of `integer`.

> [Gedmo\Exception\InvalidMappingException]   Field - [createdBy] type
>   is not valid and must be 'string' or a reference in class -
>   AyrshireMinis\CourseBundle\Entity\Category

My `Category.orm.yml` file contains the following:

```
    createdBy:
        type: string
        gedmo:
            blameable:
                on: create
```

The intention of this column is that it would represent a user ID, so an integer would make more sense than a VARCHAR(255) which this configuration will produce.

Is there a way to set this as an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would make more sense if you had a relation between user and category as ManyToOne :

```
  manyToOne:
    createdBy:
      targetEntity: User
      joinColumn:
        name: created_by
        referencedColumnName: id
```